# What is the code that appears during AUTO's analysis?

Tags: wall-e

In a deleted scene of *WALL-E*, (*"Secret Files"*), when AUTO analyses the plant, a code appears on the screen before a pop up saying "ORIGIN-EARTH".

What does this code say, and what does it mean?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a screenshot of the code, or a link to the deleted scene in question?

Comment: If it's what @Valorum thinks, then its absolute gibberish

Comment: It looks like someone keyboard mashing.  (Which is what you'd expect from what is essentially an animated storyboard.)

Comment: @F1Krazy - You can see the deleted scene that OP is referring to here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=701&v=rDzi--RV1tg&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 13):

There appears to be no coherent pattern to the text, other than the final sentence on the code which states in plain (if poorly spelled) English;

> **[POSITVE ID: AFFIRMATIVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwhtY.png)**

The remainder of the 'code' is a jumble of number and letter strings, roughly corresponding to text that's been generated by pressing keys (roughly alternating) from the right- and left-hand side of the keyboard.

[image]

> 84826
> 76823774823
>
> J\
> 82390892438
>
> J\uwer__73737737
> J\
> hjfwfhj
> 673147237889/// 67631

and

> gkopwK
> MLMKAJOIRCJQIOJOICJRIIO
> OPKMFQOIMKKOPKFO9OQICM

etc

Answer (score 8):

### It means nothing,

This is the storyboarders simply indicating that the computer is processing data.

The trope is called, "[Cool Code of Source](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoolCodeOfSource)" (warning, TVTropes link).

Especially during storyboarding, there is rarely if ever effort put into any further details.

Comment: It does appear to be writing though, with both words and numbers